# How to create letter head like this?

Tags: letterhead

I want to create letter head like this. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: You could remove all the text with an image manipulation program and then set the picture as the page background.

Answer (score 6):

As commented, I removed the text from the image template using GIMP.  You find the updated image at [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeuD0.png).  Save it as `bg.png` in the directory of your document.

Then I took an example from the [`scrlttr2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) documentation and put the background image using [`eso-pic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

```
\documentclass[
fromalign=right,
fromphone,
fromemail,
fromlogo,
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{2.5cm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\setkomavar{fromname}{John Public}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  Valley 2\\
  54321 Public-Village
}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Peter@Public.invalid}
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\begin{letter}{%
    Joana Public\\
    Hillside 1\\
    12345 Public-City
  }
  \opening{Dear chairman,}
  the last general meeting was about one year ago.
  I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
  club advises you to make a general meeting every
  six month. Because of this I expect the executive
  board to detain such a meeting immediately.
  \closing{Expecting an invitation}
  \ps PS: I hope you accept this as an friendly
  demand note.
  \setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure}
  \encl{Compendium of the constitution with the
    general meeting paragraphs.}
  \cc{executive board\\all members}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]